# Does Android Tags app recognize vcard data from an NFC tag?

Tags: android, vcf-vcard, nfc

I've been able to successfully write URL and text data to RFID tags, these are recognized by the Android Tags app, but I have been unable to get the Tags app to recognize vcard data. Where I would assume it would give me the option to add contact after scanning I only see the MIME type text/x-vcard.

Can anyone confirm whether or not the Tags app will recognize vcard data?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the tags app should be able to recognize v-card data.

I've used the NXP TagWriter app to write a vcard to a Mifare Classic card, then read it in via the Tags app.  It showed up as a contact type and allowed me to import the contact into the contacts system.

I've also had success in using the Tags app to read vcard data off of a demo NFC-enabled business card.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the recommended Android app from NXP? You can find the applications at google play: https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=NXP+Semiconductors

The TagWriter app lets you write urls, contact, text or sms. If you do so with a brand new mifare tag the app will show a message before confirmation that the tag needs to be formatted for NDEF first.

This routine worked fine for me with a new tag. A Nexus 7 tablet showed the contact card when the tag was presented afterwards.

I also tried the same routine with a tag that was previously formatted as an NDEF tag but that failed. Each time I tried it turned up as an empty NDEF tag. I used the NFC TagInfo app (see link on top) for checking the contents of that tag and it turns out that only one sector (sector 1, counting from 0) is written with the vcard information. Resulting in an incomplete tag. Because the tag is already NFC formatted the tagWriter app doesn't propose to format the tag. My guess is that it's badly formatted, not to the full 1K size size.

Make sure to enable full scan at scan level using the preferences of the taginfo app.